# tomcat 7 openmore than one process

Tags: tomcat, process, instance

I'm running tomcat7 on Centos

I have to enter the same instance from more than one URL: one is by load balancer and the second is direct connection to specific server for monitor: lb.mydomain.com and web1.mydomain.com

The problem is that I have objects that serve all connections as singeltons (use as cache objects).
The moment I enter the tomcat from two doains I see two cache objects but only one tomcat proccess (using grep)

I also have problem since I use JNI to load so library that can be loaded only once.

How is it?
Is it possible to block the tomcat7 to only one proccess (or instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your webapp is deployed twice (once for each virtual host) and since each webapp has its own classloader, you end up with duplicate singletons.

One thing to try is to move the jar containing those classes under `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` instead of putting it directly under the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. This way the classes will be loaded only once by Tomcat's common classloader.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
The webapp is deployed only once but seems to run in two intances / preccesses for each domain.
I'll try to move the lib as yuo suggested to $catalina_home